# I'm a beginner, trying to write a function that finds the root of an array function

Tags: c++, arrays

I've been working for a couple hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  All I need to do is find one root from a polynomial represented by an array using Newton's method.  The two functions (polyval and polyder) seem to be giving me the right answers, and I feel that the main code is correctly doing Newton's method.  I was hoping someone experienced could give me some advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

float polyval(float*, int, float);
void polyder(float*, int, float*);

int main(void)  {
    int n;
    float x=-1,f;
    float tol=pow(10,-5);

    cout << "Enter polynomial order:" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    float* p=new float[n+1];
    float* dp=new float[n];

    cout << "Enter coefficients, starting with the highest power:" << endl;
    for (int k=0;k<n+1;k++) {
        cin >> p[k];
    }

    polyder(p,n,dp);
    f=polyval(p,n,x);

    while (fabs(f)>tol) {
        x=x-f/polyval(dp,n,x);
        f=polyval(p,n,x);
        cout << x << endl;
        cout << f << endl;
    }

    cout << "A real root is at x= " << x << endl;
    cout << "To verify: p(" << x << ") = " << polyval(p,n,x) << endl;

    return 0;
}

float polyval(float* p, int n, float x) {
    float px;
    px=0;

    for (int k=0;k<n+1;k++) {
        px=px+p[k]*pow(x,n-k);
    }

    return px;
}

void polyder(float* p, int n, float* dp) {
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++) {
        dp[k] = p[k+1] * (k+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If everything is giving you the right answer, what do you have problems with?

Comment: Well the polyder and polyva functions give me numerically correct answers.  But the problem lies somewhere in the main function since the values for x and f keep increasing exponentially whenever I enter a polynomial.

Comment: Where is the C++ in this C code beside the use of C++ includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `polyval(dp,n,x)` will access beyond the allocated space for `dp`, which has `n` entries and not the requred `n+1`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I've been working for about 3 hours trying to figure it out, now I can finally get some sleep :)

Comment: Using `std::vector` and `std::vector::at()` instead of c-arrays and raw pointer arithmetic would have given you your sleep much earlier.